how to use index when searched column is not indexed but has the same ordering as the indexed primary key
I have a huge table (kind of audit log) with these columns:
ID, TS, DATA


ID is the primary key, and it is a number from a sequence.
TS is a timestamp and it is the current timestamp of the insert.
DATA is the useful data.

There is an index on the primary key (ID).
There is a guarantee that if record "B" has a greater ID than record "A" then the TS of "B" will be greater or equal to TS of "A".
My goal is to select the records for a given time interval. The time interval is always very short compared to the total time the table covers (days vs years).
There is no index on TS and I can not create one (explanation: The reason is that the audit table on the production system has a few thousand million rows. The DBAs fear that a new index will unnecesseraly slow down inserts into the log. Actually my query will not be a frequent one and will use only a small part of the table).
If I simply ask
select * 
from audit 
where TS > 20220101 and TS < 20220102

then a full table scan happens which takes way too much time.
If I find out first the first ID for each day, and get the knowledge that the first ID for 20220101 is 123456 and the first id for 20220102 is 145678 then I can ask
select * 
from audit 
where ID > 123456 and ID < 145678

which is quick because an index scan happens.
So it is obvious that instead of the full table scan I should somehow find out the first and last ID for the given time period and use them. IT is also obvious that I can find out the IDs quickly via binary search, because of the correlation between the IDs and the TSs. But I don't know how to do this in a SQL query, if it is possible at all.
So is it possible to make use of the ID index for this query? If yes, how?
Is it possible to somehow hint for the DB engine that there is a correlation between ID and TS ?

your question is misleading, you dont want to use an index on ts or data so i dont know  how to help u to use the index. what you are asking how to select specific data using ID column. Beside you can add parallel hint in your query if you are using full table scan but again it depend on your environment how much is busy

You are trying to implement an index manually. Why don't you leave that to the database? It will be much more efficient.

Yep. Just create an index on TS. If you try to use the ID index instead to do a binary search for the TS range in there, this will become quite complicated and probably very slow. Much slower than the original slow query.

Just index that TS col and be done with it. It's unreasonable to operate under the restriction that you can't add an index.

Can you explain why you cannot add indexes to the database? Can you create objects like a package? (You could possibly create a package that could simulate an index by using session state to cache a mapping of days to IDs, and then call the package in a SQL statement.) Also, what version of Oracle are you using? (If you're on 12.2 or later, you could possibly put your PL/SQL code into a common table expression procedure, and call it from SQL. This would lead to a very ugly SQL statement though.)

Please clarify via edits not comments & delete & flag obsolete comments.

I don't know why you just commented, especially given my last comment, especially in response to it. Please act on my last comment & the rest of the feedback & site help & meta Q&A. Commentary is not for discussion, it is for requesting clarifying edits & noting post problems. The site is for Q&A & not discussion. Moreover comments are ephemeral. https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment [ask] [Help]

Below are some options to solve your problem:

Build the index The DBA's fear of indexing is unfounded. Indexes exist precisely for these kind of problems. Indexes are built to grow, and in some ways they work better for large tables than they do for small tables. There's nothing unusual about multiple indexes on a billion row table. The table already has one index for the primary key - how much would a second index hurt?
Schedule the query If a query isn't run often enough to justify an index, then it usually also doesn't matter if the query takes a long time to finish. If the query is only used once a week, can't you just wait an hour? If this query is part of some review you have to perform every day, and you don't want to wait an hour every morning, then automate the query with some combination of DBMS_SCHEDULER, a PL/SQL block to turn the results into an HTML table, and sending the results with UTL_MAIL.
Parallelism If you can't work smarter, work harder. Use multiple threads to make the full table scan run more quickly. Just change your query to SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(X) */ ... where X is some reasonable number of threads. Be careful not to use too much parallelism. If your DBAs are scared of an index, they probably hate parallelism.
Partition Partitioning creates multiple physical objects that Oracle can almost instantly switch between. This might work perfectly in your scenario, since your queries appear to be relatively coarse, and Oracle has a convenient interval partitioning approach that stores one day's worth of data in one physical table.

alter table audit_table
modify partition by range(ts) interval(numtodsinterval(1, 'DAY'))
(
    --Pick the earlest day here:
    partition p1 values less than (date '2020-01-01')
);


Materialized zone map (If you have an Exadata system. I haven't tested this code or concept.) A materialized zone map on the TS column might work well as a pseudo index. The zone maps stores the min and max values for a group of blocks. Since your values are loaded in order, your table data might be ordered enough for those mins and maxes to help quickly identify the relevant blocks.

create materialized zonemap audit_tabl_zm on audit_table(ts);


Binary-search of related index Use one the existing answers, possibly as part of a function or CTE, or possibly you can use the IDs returned and then manually plug them into an existing query. While this works, it's not ideal because you shouldn't have to significantly change your queries to get good performance.
Also, are you sure that the primary key and the timestamp are perfectly synchronized? Using sequences to have any meaning, even an order, can be dangerous. For example, if you have Real Application Clusters, and the sequence was not explicitly set to ORDER, each instance will have a separate cache and the IDs will not be in order.



+1 for the effort and especially for the PK - TS correlation insight :-) . Actually I become aware of this when the binary sort gave slightly different results in some cases. It turned out that correlation is not perfect because of sequence value caching. I compensated for this with adding an extra day to the begin and end of the interval.

To answer your question about "But I don't know how to do this in a SQL query, if it is possible at all."
you can do it with a recursive CTE:
with minmax(minid, maxid, midid) as (
    select min(id), max(id), trunc((min(id) + max(id))/2) from audit_logs
)
, cte(lvl, lolim, hilim, midid, id, midts, val, targetts) as (
    select 1, minid, maxid, midid, d1.id, d1.ts, d1.val,
        :p_target_timestamp)
    from minmax d
    join audit_logs d1 on d1.id = midid
    
    union all
    
    select lvl+1,
        case when c.targetts < c.midts then c.lolim else c.midid end,
        case when c.targetts < c.midts then c.midid else c.hilim  end,
        trunc( (case when c.targetts < c.midts then c.lolim else c.midid end + case when c.targetts < c.midts then c.midid else c.hilim  end) / 2 ),
        d1.id,
        d1.ts, d1.val, c.targetts
    from cte c
    , lateral( select d1.id, d3.ts, d3.val
        from (
            select max(id) as id 
                from audit_logs d2 
                where d2.id <= 
                    trunc( (case when c.targetts < c.midts then c.lolim else c.midid end + case when c.targetts < c.midts then c.midid else c.hilim  end) / 2 )
        ) d1
        join audit_logs d3 on d3.id = d1.id
    ) d1
    where d1.id <> c.id
)
cycle id set is_cycle to 1 default 0
select ...

Complete example with random data: https://dbfiddle.uk/UMqLf6wz

+1 for this massive effort! What I understood from this is that one can use CTE for calculating the ID boundaries. But that can be done with the pl sql block I created as well and that seems to me less complex.

Yes, it was just an exercice to see if possible... and also no guarantee at all it could be more efficient, anyway it could inspire 2 little improvements in the PL/SQL version: stop the loop when "mid" doesn't change from one iteration to the other instead of imposing a fixed limit, and merge the 2 SELECT into one to avoid 1 round trip.

I wrote a pl sql for finding out the ID boundaries for a given date. It seems working and runs very quickly (as expected).
Here is it:
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
    tsParam date := TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2021-06-13T00:00:00.000+0100', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM');
    lolim number(19,0) := 0;
    hilim number(19,0) := 0;
    mid number(19,0) := 0;
    ts date;
    i number(19,0) := 0;
    tsParamIsLater boolean;
BEGIN
    select min(AUDIT_LOG_ID) into lolim from audit_logs;
    select max(AUDIT_LOG_ID) into hilim from audit_logs;

    loop
        dbms_output.put_line('lolim: ' || lolim || ', hilim: ' || hilim);

        i := i + 1;

        mid := (lolim + hilim) / 2;
        select max(audit_log_id) into mid from audit_logs where audit_log_id < mid;
        select created_date into ts from audit_logs where audit_log_id = mid;
        tsParamIsLater := tsParam > ts;
        if tsParamIsLater then
            lolim := mid;
        else
            hilim := mid;
        end if;

        -- table size is a few thousand million rows max, so at the 40th round we should be fine
        if (i > 40) then
            exit;
        end if;

    end loop;
END;
/

and here is the output:
lolim: 1, hilim: 64411511
lolim: 1, hilim: 32205755
lolim: 16102877, hilim: 32205755
lolim: 24154315, hilim: 32205755
lolim: 28180034, hilim: 32205755
lolim: 30192894, hilim: 32205755
lolim: 30192894, hilim: 31199324
lolim: 30696108, hilim: 31199324
lolim: 30696108, hilim: 30947715
lolim: 30821911, hilim: 30947715
lolim: 30884812, hilim: 30947715
lolim: 30884812, hilim: 30916263
lolim: 30900537, hilim: 30916263
lolim: 30900537, hilim: 30908399
lolim: 30900537, hilim: 30904467
lolim: 30902501, hilim: 30904467
lolim: 30902501, hilim: 30903483
lolim: 30902991, hilim: 30903483
lolim: 30902991, hilim: 30903236
lolim: 30903113, hilim: 30903236
lolim: 30903174, hilim: 30903236
lolim: 30903204, hilim: 30903236
lolim: 30903219, hilim: 30903236
lolim: 30903227, hilim: 30903236
lolim: 30903231, hilim: 30903236
lolim: 30903233, hilim: 30903236
lolim: 30903233, hilim: 30903234
lolim: 30903233, hilim: 30903234
lolim: 30903233, hilim: 30903234
lolim: 30903233, hilim: 30903234
lolim: 30903233, hilim: 30903234
lolim: 30903233, hilim: 30903234
lolim: 30903233, hilim: 30903234
lolim: 30903233, hilim: 30903234
lolim: 30903233, hilim: 30903234
lolim: 30903233, hilim: 30903234
lolim: 30903233, hilim: 30903234
lolim: 30903233, hilim: 30903234
lolim: 30903233, hilim: 30903234
lolim: 30903233, hilim: 30903234
lolim: 30903233, hilim: 30903234

But I am still looking for a simpler way.
Is it not possible to somehow hint for the DB engine that there is a guarantee that if record "B" has a greater ID than record "A" then the timestamp of "B" will be greater or equal to timestamp of "A" ?
NOTE: actually in my scenario the correlation between ID and TS was not perfect. The ID was coming from a sequence and beacuse of caching of the sequence values there were a few records where bigger IDs had earlier TS es. This discrepancy was always less than a few hundred records so I compensated it with widening the search limits one day.
